# why does not it enter into arg1 if condion, though arg1 is commandline argument

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    flag=1;
elif ! [[ "$1" == "arg1" || "$1" == "arg2" || "$1" == "arg3" || ...... ]]; then 
    echo "Invalid"
    flag=1;
fi

if [ "$flag" == "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage of script...."
    exit
fi
count="$(ls *.mov | wc -l)"
if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]] 
then
    echo there are 0 .mov files in this path
elif [[ "$count" -eq 1 ]] 
then
    echo there is 1 .mov file in this path
    vlc *.mov
elif [[ $1 = "arg1" ]] ; then
    echo entered the tough part....coz its not entering`enter code here`
elif [[ "$1" == "arg2" ]] || [[ "$1" == "arg10" ]] ; then
    echo entered here atleast...but not entering 
else
    script continues
```

The code does not enter elif conditions involving command line arguments. Tried =, ==, -eq, double square braces, single square braces. But it does not enter, pls help

Answer (score 1):

1. you should add a disclaimer at the head of the script: " #!/bin/bash"
2. I tried your script and it does get into the elif.
   the code I used is:

   ```
   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then

   echo "not 1 arg"

   flag=1;

   elif ! [[ "$1" == "arg1" || "$1" == "arg2" || "$1" == "arg3"  ]]; then

   echo "Invalid"

   flag=1;

   else

   echo "else"

   fi
   ```

and the input/output are:

$ . script.sh 1 2

not 1 arg

$ . script.sh 1

Invalid

$ . script.sh arg1

else

I tried the second part and it is also working:

```
count=$2

if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]] ;then

    echo "there are 0 .mov files in this path"

elif [[ "$count" -eq 1 ]] ;then

    echo "there is 1 .mov file in this path"

    vlc *.mov

elif [[ $1 = "arg1" ]] ; then

    echo "arg1 "

elif [[ "$1" == "arg2" ]] || [[ "$1" == "arg10" ]] ; then

    echo "arg2 or arg10 "

else

echo "else"

fi
```

and tested it (second argument is "count"):
$ . script.sh arg1 0
there are 0 .mov files in this path
$ . script.sh 1 0
there are 0 .mov files in this path
$ . script.sh arg10 0
there are 0 .mov files in this path
$ . script.sh arg1 1
there is 1 .mov file in this path
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed.  To run 'vlc' please ask your administrator to install the package 'vlc-nox'
$ . script.sh arg10 1
there is 1 .mov file in this path
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed.  To run 'vlc' please ask your administrator to install the package 'vlc-nox'
$ . script.sh 1 1
there is 1 .mov file in this path
The program 'vlc' is currently not installed.  To run 'vlc' please ask your administrator to install the package 'vlc-nox'
$ . script.sh arg1 2
arg1
$ . script.sh 1 2
else
$ . script.sh arg10 2
arg2 or arg10

Comment: I have problems not with that elif, but elifs with last two elifs

Comment: I tried also the second part and it worked.
maybe the "exit" take you out of the script?

Comment: If these two lines added to second part of your script, at the beginning  and end, uncommented -> goes to else part. This is my problem. What to do? 
Commented -> goeds to arg1. 
line 1(at the beginning pls add)#find . -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && 

and last line (at the end please add)#)' ';'

Comment: running  two processes at the same time, one process is cd to all directories available, the other is if condition makes the script to go to else part, and not the arg1 condition part. Can anyone pls solve this ?

Comment: you can use sleep or wait that:"suspend script execution until all jobs running in background have terminated, or until the job number
or process ID specified as an option terminates"

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the bash *case* statement http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29

For this particular script, it will make your script easier to read and your branching problem will most likely go away..

Answer (score 0):

if your purpose is to handle the arguments passed to the script by command line it's better to use the `getopts` bash 
this is just an example that you can adapt to your scope:

```
#!/bin/bash
function usage {
  echo "usage: ..."
}

while getopts f:o:h opt; do
  case $opt in
    f)
      fileName=$OPTARG
      echo "filename[$fileName]"
      ;;
    o)
      otherargs=$OPTARG
      echo "otherargs[$otherargs]"
      ;;
    h)
      usage && exit 0
      ;;
    ?)
      usage && exit 2
      ;;
  esac
done
~
```

output

```
[myShell] ➤ ./n -h
usage: ...

[myShell] ➤ ./n -f myfilename
filename[myfilename]

[myShell] ➤ ./n -o other
otherargs[other]

[myShell] ➤ ./n -l
./n: illegal option -- l
usage: ...
```